# SQL UPDATE WITH CONCATENE FIELD

Tags: sql, concatenation

Hy Everyone,

I have the follwing table

```
mysql> select * from recipes;
+------+-------+
| id   | direct|
+------+-------+
|    1 | max   |
|    2 | linda |
|    3 | sam   |
|    4 | henry |
+------+-------+
```

But a need to update all direct field and put `{{  }}` at the beginning and at the end of the field.

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | direct    |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | {{max}}   |
|    2 | {{linda}} |
|    3 | {{sam}}   |
|    4 | {{henry}} |
+------+-----------+
```

How can I do that?

I tried `UPDATE recipes SET direct = '{"step": [{ "description": "'+direct+'","image": ""}]}'`, but it does not work for me.

Please help me!!!

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. At most, you should use a computed column for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. using concat

```
update recipes set direct = concat('{{',direct,'}}')
```

Comment: I tried this, but all the direct data were converted to '0'

Comment: gordon's solution should work fine... as well as concat

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that should work in any database:

```
UPDATE recipes
    SET direct = REPLACE('{{x}}', 'x', direct);
```